# Show that if f is analytic and non-constant on a compact domain, Re f and Im f assume their maxima and minima on the boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if f is analytic and non-constant on a compact domain, Re f and Im f assume their maxima and minima on the boundary

My proposal is to use Open Mapping Theorem, this is the image under f of any open set D containing $z_{0}$ in its interior is an open set containing $f (z_{0})$ in its interior.
Could someone help me through this problem?

Comment: Using the open mapping theorem is a good idea. Try arguing by contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Look at $e^{f(x)}$ and $e^{if(x)}$. What are their absolute values?